# Hash not returning values from gets.chomp

Tags: ruby

For some reason the hash I created doesn't return the value when I try to get argument from the command line.

Here's the code

```
DIAL_BOOK = {
    "East Bay": 510,
    "San Francisco": 415,
    "San Jose": 650,
}

city = gets.chomp

if city == "East Bay"
   puts "Area Code: #{DIAL_BOOK[city]}       
end
```

Output Results

```
Which area code would you like to find out 
East Bay
Area Code:
```

I'm completely confused on what's going on here. When I hard code "East Bay" to the hash it returns me 510 just fine. Anybody have an suggestion on what's going on?

Comment: `puts "Area Code: #{DIAL_BOOK[city.to_sym]}"`

Comment: Wow that worked, for some reason when I use rockets in the hash i'm able to display the area code but when it go back into colons I have to add to_sym to them. Does anybody know why it does this?

Answer (score 4):

1. You're passing in a symbol, `:city`, instead of the actual variable `city`.
2. String interpolation is done with a `#` and not a `$` (e.g. `#{DIAL_BOOK[city]}`).
3. Your hash's keys are symbols but `city` contains a string. Either change your hash to use strings as keys (`DIAL_BOOK = { 'Easy Bay' => 510 }`) or convert the city to a symbol before lookup (`#{DIAL_BOOK[city.to_sym]`).

Additionally, you may want to simplify and remove your `if` condition unless you specifically only want to print the value for "East Bay".

Comment: I switched over to just using city, but it was giving me the same issues. 

I switched the colons into => and for some reason the values were displaying. I'm not exactly sure what's going on.

Comment: Right. By defining your hash with `{ 'foo': 'bar' }` as you are, the keys are getting converted to symbols. Thus `{ 'foo': 'bar' } # => { :foo => bar }` If you want the keys to remain as strings, you'll need to use the hashrocket, `{ 'foo' => 'bar' }`. Alternatively, you can convert city to a symbol (`city.to_sym`) and look that up instead. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: Is there any issue when I use `to_sym`? So let's I want them to remain as strings, that means I automatically have to use `to_sym`. Is that correct?

Comment: Both options are viable.

Understand that currently, your hash does not use string keys, but symbol keys. Although `"foo"` declares a string, `:"foo"` declares a symbol, `:foo`. Similarly, `{ 'foo': 'bar' }` declares a hash containing the key `:foo` (as a symbol). If you really want string keys, then you'll have to use the hashrocket syntax `{ 'foo' => 'bar' }`.

Personally, in this scenario I'd just use the hashrocket syntax, because I think symbols with spaces and capitals are just a little weird — in order to declare one, you'd usually have to use `:'Foo Bar'` or `'Foo Bar'.to_sym`.

Comment: So in short: you need `city.to_sym` if you use the `{ 'foo': 'bar' }` syntax, but not with `{ 'foo' => 'bar' }`.

Comment: I guess I didn't read the ruby style guide completely but I'm guessing  symbols are preferred over strings?

Comment: @Shinne it's not a question of good or bad style. A hash allows any object type as its keys. Use whatever suits your needs. (string-integer-pairs seem like a reasonable choice)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `city` is different from symbol `:city`. To interpolate string in ruby use 
 `#{expression}` inside a double quotes because double quotes allow for escape sequences while single quotes do not.

```
city = gets.chomp
puts "Area Code: #{DIAL_BOOK[city]}" if city == "East Bay"
```

For strings as keys in hash, use rocket `=>`instead of `:`. Otherwise you will have to use `city.to_sym` instead of `city`.

```
DIAL_BOOK = {
    "East Bay" => 510,
    "San Francisco" => 415,
    "San Jose" => 650,
}
```

The rocket operator can take in any literal that aren't valid labels. A `:` assumes a valid label on its left. `DIAL_BOOK[:'East Bay'] #=> 510`

```
{ :$set => 11 }                       # Valid
{ $set: 11 }                          # Invalid
{ :'where.is.pancakes.house?' => 23 } # Valid
{ 'where.is.pancakes.house?': 23 }    # Invalid
```

Comment: I had some typos earlier, but the to_sym seemed to work. I thought : were the preferred way to do hash instead of rocket.

Comment: You cannot avoid using rocket especially for string keys. See the answer.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful.